# Blender Installer Error Message (.msi Installer 2.78b)

Tags: installation

I downloaded from [blender's website](https://www.blender.org/download/) the installer for the program (ver. 2.78c). I open it, and this pops up:

[image: _This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package._]

Is there something I'm missing here?
Thanks.

Comment: Possibly corrupt download. Download again or use the zipped package instead.

Comment: How do I use the zipped package? All I see are data files. Do I compress and open?

Comment: Unzip the the whole archive anywhere in your computer and run `Blender.exe`.